# amqp.connect is not able to maintain connection alive forever

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

My code is as shown below :

rabbitmq.js

```
const connectRabbitMq = () => {
    amqp.connect(process.env.CLOUDAMQP_MQTT_URL, function (err, conn) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            console.log('[AMQP] reconnecting in 1s');
            setTimeout(connectRabbitMq, 1);
            return;
        }
        conn.createChannel((err, ch) => {
            if (!err) {
                console.log('Channel created');
                channel = ch;
                connection = conn;
            }
        });

        conn.on("error", function (err) {
            if (err.message !== "Connection closing") {
                console.error("[AMQP] conn error", err.message);
            }
        });

        conn.on("close", function () {
            console.error("[AMQP] reconnecting");
            connectRabbitMq();
        });
    })

};


const sendMessage = () => {


    let data = {
        user_id: 1,
        test_id: 2
    };

    if (channel) {
        channel.sendToQueue(q, new Buffer(JSON.stringify(data)), {
            persistent: true
        });
    }

    else {

        connectRabbitMq(() => {
            channel.sendToQueue(q, new Buffer(JSON.stringify(data)), {
                persistent: true
            });
        })
    }
};


const receiveMessage = () => {

    if (channel) {

        channel.consume(q, function (msg) {
            // ch.ack(msg);
            console.log(" [x] Received %s", msg.content.toString());
        });
    }

    else {

        connectRabbitMq(() => {
            channel.consume(q, function (msg) {
                // ch.ack(msg);
                console.log(" [x] Received %s", msg.content.toString());
            });
        })
    }
}
```

scheduler.js

```
let cron = require('node-cron');


const callMethodForeverRabbitMq = () => {


    cron.schedule('*/1 * * * * *', function () {

        rabbitMqClientPipeline.receiveMessage();
    });


};
```

app.js

```
rabbitmq.sendMessage();
```

now what happens here is , the code is not able to maintain the connection alive forever . so is there any way I can keep it alive forever ?

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if you are using Promise api or callback API.

With Promise API you can do it like this:

```
const amqp = require('amqplib');

const delay = (ms) => new Promise((resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms)));

const connectRabbitMq = () => amqp.connect('amqp://127.0.0.1:5672')
  .then((conn) => {
    conn.on('error', function (err) {
      if (err.message !== 'Connection closing') {
        console.error('[AMQP] conn error', err.message);
      }
    });

    conn.on('close', function () {
      console.error('[AMQP] reconnecting');
      connectRabbitMq();
    });

    //connection = conn;

    return conn.createChannel();
  })
  .then(ch => {
    console.log('Channel created');
    //channel = ch;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    console.log('[AMQP] reconnecting in 1s');
    return delay(1000).then(() => connectRabbitMq())
  });

connectRabbitMq();
```

With callback API like this:

```
const amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');

const connectRabbitMq = () => {
  amqp.connect('amqp://127.0.0.1:5672', function (err, conn) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      console.log('[AMQP] reconnecting in 1s');
      setTimeout(connectRabbitMq, 1000);
      return;
    }
    conn.createChannel((err, ch) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log('Channel created');
        //channel = ch;
        //connection = conn;
      }
    });

    conn.on("error", function (err) {
      if (err.message !== "Connection closing") {
        console.error("[AMQP] conn error", err.message);
      }
    });

    conn.on("close", function () {
      console.error("[AMQP] reconnecting");
      connectRabbitMq();
    });
  })
};

connectRabbitMq();
```

**UPDATE** new code with request buffering

```
const buffer = [];
let connection = null;
let channel = null;

const connectRabbitMq = () => {
  amqp.connect('amqp://127.0.0.1:5672', function (err, conn) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      console.log('[AMQP] reconnecting in 1s');
      setTimeout(connectRabbitMq, 1000);
      return;
    }
    conn.createChannel((err, ch) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log('Channel created');
        channel = ch;
        connection = conn;

        while (buffer.length > 0) {
          const request = buffer.pop();
          request();
        }
      }
    });

    conn.once("error", function (err) {
      channel = null;
      connection = null;

      if (err.message !== "Connection closing") {
        console.error("[AMQP] conn error", err.message);
      }
    });

    conn.once("close", function () {
      channel = null;
      connection = null;

      console.error("[AMQP] reconnecting");
      connectRabbitMq();
    });
  })
};

const sendMessage = () => {
  let data = {
    user_id: 1,
    test_id: 2
  };

  if (channel) {
    channel.sendToQueue(q, new Buffer(JSON.stringify(data)), {
      persistent: true
    });
  }
  else {
    buffer.push(() => {
      channel.sendToQueue(q, new Buffer(JSON.stringify(data)), {
        persistent: true
      });
    });
  }
};

const receiveMessage = () => {
  if (channel) {
    channel.consume(q, function (msg) {
      // ch.ack(msg);
      console.log(" [x] Received %s", msg.content.toString());
    });
  }
  else {
    buffer.push(() => {
      channel.consume(q, function (msg) {
        // ch.ack(msg);
        console.log(" [x] Received %s", msg.content.toString());
      });
    })
  }
};
```

There are edge cases where this code won't work - for example it won't reestablish `queue.consume` unless it's called explicitly. But overall this hopefully gives you idea on how to implement proper recovery...

Comment: I have implemented the code as you have suggested.it gives me the following error for milliseconds .  `stack: 'IllegalOperationError: Channel closed\n    at Channel.<anonymous> (/Users/mrugeshthaker/selltm-backend/node_modules/amqplib/lib/channel.js:149:11)\n `

Comment: The error is unrelated - this means your Channel is closed and you are trying to use it... Maybe share more code or ask another question.

Comment: To support reconnecting you would have to change architecture of you program. You would have to buffer requests when the connection is down and then later replay them when the connection is up. Perhaps it would be better if you let the program crash when you lose connection and restart it...